# I want to copy the Some of entire row having same word in the first column as in A3,A4,A5,A6 & paste to another sheet from the vacant rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some rows in copySheet.sheet1 having some special keyword in first column as "Ojha" . So I want to copy those entire row having "Ojha" in first row & paste it into another pasteSheet.sheet2 . At first I found that cell Having "Ojha". So I put it in Foundcell. So now I used...:

```
Foundcell.EntireRow.Copy
```

& in another sheet first I find the vacant rows from where the rows will paste, so

```
RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(pasteSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1

pasteSheet.Range("A" & RowCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

so it pasted only first row having "Ojha"
So now I want to copy all those rows which are having "Ojha" in the first column & paste to pasteSheet next to next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to loop through the cells, this will work

```
Sub Loopy()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))
    End With

    With ws
        For Each c In rng.Cells

            If c = "Ojha" Then
                c.EntireRow.Copy
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If

        Next c
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = 0

End Sub
```

You can also use an autofilter macro...

Comment: finds the last row in column A and sets the range

Comment: Thanks for answer. just have a doubt that what this line 'll do?? As rws is find the total row on the basis of A Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))

Comment: "A" is column A. Why don't you run the code and see if it works.

Comment: Add `rng.select` and see what gets selected. You didn't supply a code so I had to make my own.